# How to change/adapt loss function while using "class" incremental learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

As a beginner on class incremental learning and trying to understand the general concept. In class incremental learning, we have a model that can make a classification between classes A, B, and C. By using data from another class D, we want to apply class incremental learning to obtain a model which can predict classes among A, B, C and D without training all data with all classes from scratch.

My **question** is, since our softmax (that we use to calculate loss (cross-entropy loss)) has a fixed size (3 in case of A, B, and C classes), how this can be possible? Do we change the loss in class incremental learning? How to deal with that?

Note 1: The video I watched to get an idea about class incremental learning is [iCaRL- incremental Classifier and Representation Learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCKi41BHDAk&ab_channel=ManikVarma).

Note 2: I saw the catastrophic forgetting issue, but my question does not cover this. It is (I suppose) more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

In class incremental learning, we do change the softmax function and associated loss in each stage of learning.

Class incremental learning is a fairly new field of research, and one of the earliest and among the most influential papers in this field is [iCaRL: Incremental Classifier and Representation Learning](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Rebuffi_iCaRL_Incremental_Classifier_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf) by Rebuffi et al. (2017). There, this change of loss function is detailed in section 2.3 and Algorithm 3. The augmented loss function includes the *classification loss* corresponding to new data and also the *distillation loss*, which preserves previously learned discriminative information. Incorporating the distillation loss in the augmented loss function mitigates the chance of catastrophic forgetting as well.